# Firefox WebExtension, run script once on page load

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

my current script is designed to redirect the page if it has a URL in an array. My script will (I think) redirect the page but then continue to redirect it (resulting in a constantly loading page). Is there a way to only run the script once or end the script?

Script:

```
var blocked = ["http://example.org", "http://example.com"];
function check () {
    for (i = 0; i < blocked.length; i++ ) {
        var item = blocked[i];
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (blocked[i] == url) {
            return "interface/redirect.html";
        }
    }
    return url;
}
window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL(check());
```

Both the below attempts did not work either:

```
var blocked = ["http://example.org", "http://example.com"];
var ran = false;
function check () {
    for (i = 0; i < blocked.length; i++ ) {
        var item = blocked[i];
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (blocked[i] == url) {
            return "interface/redirect.html"
        }
    }
    return url;
}
if (ran == false) {
    window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL( check () );
    ran = true;
}
```

and

```
var blocked = ["http://example.org", "http://example.com"];
function check () {
    for (i = 0; i < blocked.length; i++ ) {
        var item = blocked[i];
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (blocked[i] == url) {
            return "interface/redirect.html";
        }
    }
    return url;
}
window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL(check());
var x = 0;
while (x == 0) {

};
```

My script is currently run via `"content_scripts"`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "js": ["redirect.js"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, since content scripts are not injected into `chrome-extension:` pages, for a *blocked* URL you won't get any loops.

However, you do risk a loop for URLs that *aren't* blocked, since even if you assign the same value to `window.location`, it will reload the page.

Further, passing a real URL to `chrome.runtime.getURL()` will mangle it - so, fortunately, you won't get loops, but you wouldn't be able to visit any page either.

So, your code should simply *not* assign in the "allowed" case.

```
function check () {
    if (blocked.includes(window.location.href)) {
        window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL("interface/redirect.html");
    }
}
check();
```

(Method used: [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes))

That said, you're using a wrong tool for the job. The proper approach to take is to use `webRequest` API. It would allow you to redirect far more efficiently than that and is specifically designed for the job. See [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#examples) from Chrome docs.

Comment: You might as well change this to using normal Array methods rather than the extra code of using a loop to iterate through the array yourself. At a minimum, move the `url` assignment out of the loop. It's not like `window.location.href` is going to change. Given that it's an extension, you could just use `if(blocked.includes(window.location.href)){window.location = chrome.runtime.getURL("interface/redirect.html");}`